# Dialogflow Knowledge Base CSV Upload error

Tags: dialogflow-es

So I'm trying to upload an FAQ CSV file into my knowledge base. But every time I create, it will say "canceled" and at the bottom right corner it will just give me a pop up that says "error" and nothing else. Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's a screenshot of what it shows when I press "Create": https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnepr.jpg

Comment: Can you share the PDF if possible so I can help you further.

Comment: @DhruvRajkotia Hi Dhruv. I just managed to fix the problem. While checking the error logs, I seemed to have failed to notice one that said "Uncaught (in promise) {code: 3, message: "Document  contains invalid UTF-8 data. Only UTF-8 encoding is supported."}". As it turns out, I the encoding on it was wrong which was causing the issue. I have managed to fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my issue. I noticed in my console that it had mentioned the file was not encoded using UTF-8, which is why it wasn't uploading. I fixed the issue by opening my CSV file with Sublime and clicking on "Save with Encoding" and select UTF-8. Thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I realized my .csv did not have a proper end of file. When I opened it up with Sublime, I saw many lines with '`,`' after my text. I deleted those and saved it as UTF-8. My problem went away.

Just thought to share:

[image: screenshot]